# connect two sql query with AND

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a two SQL query. They have a result but when I connect them with AND , I can't get a result. 
How can I connect them together ? 
Thanks.

The description on the picture and SQL syntax on the code segment.

First one

`select KATALOGKAYITID from KatalogEtiketleri where 
((EtiketId =41 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'a' and Deger = 'tur')  or (EtiketId =41 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'a' and Deger = 'ing'))`

`

Secon One

```
 select KATALOGKAYITID from KatalogEtiketleri where 
((EtiketId =260 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'c' and Deger > '2015')  and (EtiketId =260 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'c' and Deger < '2017'))
```

Third One

```
select KATALOGKAYITID from KatalogEtiketleri where 
((EtiketId =41 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'a' and Deger = 'tur')  or (EtiketId =41 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'a' and Deger = 'ing'))  
and ((EtiketId =260 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'c' and Deger > '2015')  and (EtiketId =260 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'c' and Deger < '2017')) group by KATALOGKAYITID
```

[image]

Comment: It's only mean that you have no rows with both conditions. Your query result is a column with values.

Comment: You probably want `OR` instead of `AND`.

Comment: Yeah in your image, at the bottom, where you have the two little lines, change that to OR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all the data, You should use `UNION ALL`

```
( select KATALOGKAYITID from KatalogEtiketleri where 
((EtiketId =41 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'a' and Deger = 'tur')  or (EtiketId =41 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'a' and Deger = 'ing'))
)
UNION ALL
( select KATALOGKAYITID from KatalogEtiketleri where 
((EtiketId =260 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'c' and Deger > '2015')  and (EtiketId =260 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'c' and Deger < '2017'))
);
```

If you want data which is common between both the queries, you should use `INTERSECT`

```
( select KATALOGKAYITID from KatalogEtiketleri where 
((EtiketId =41 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'a' and Deger = 'tur')  or (EtiketId =41 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'a' and Deger = 'ing'))
)
INTERSECT
( select KATALOGKAYITID from KatalogEtiketleri where 
((EtiketId =260 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'c' and Deger > '2015')  and (EtiketId =260 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'c' and Deger < '2017'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your third select is wrong - if take a look closer, you trying to `SELECT ... WHERE EtiketId =41 ...AND... EtiketId = 260` - no rows will be in result, of course.
PL/SQL have a special operator for your problem - INTERSECT: it only returns the rows selected by all queries or data sets. If a record exists in one query and in the other. So, your code must be:

```
select KATALOGKAYITID from KatalogEtiketleri where 
((EtiketId =41 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'a' and Deger = 'tur')  or (EtiketId =41 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'a' and Deger = 'ing'))
INTERSECT
select KATALOGKAYITID from KatalogEtiketleri where 
((EtiketId =260 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'c' and Deger > '2015')  and (EtiketId =260 and ETIKETALTKARAKTERID = 'c' and Deger < '2017'))
```